# Marketing Cloud API for Admin Users

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, permissions, userrecordaccess

I am creating an external tool to help with auditing user access across multiple applications. One of those on the list is Marketing Cloud to be able to see which users have accounts and their status.

I am trying to find out if I can get this information from the API but I am coming up short.

I have an API user with Read on the User object, but it doesn't seem to let me access it.

When I make a retrieve call to "UserAccess", I get the following error: `Error: The specified principal does not have permission to view the requested UserAccess data`.

Can I access this user list through an API?

Comment: Can you provide the api call you are making

Comment: @EazyE - I found a SOAP call for `AccountUser` but it doesn't look like the data I need is exposed. I was specifically looking for the `FederationObject`, but when I do a `describe` in the SOAP call, it sells me its not retrievable `<IsRetrievable>false</IsRetrievable>`